# PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'

Tags: oracle, jobs, plsql-developer

we are getting this error when we try to create this scheduler_job  but we try to create it give us this error:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
(  job_name=>'PROC_TKN_WA_FIX_ARREARS',
   job_type=>'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   ownname=>'BUSINESSDATA_ARGENTINA' ,
   job_action=>'BEGIN BUSINESSDATA_ARGENTINA.PROC_TKN_WA_FIX_ARREARS; END;',
   start_date=> SYSTIMESTAMP,
   repeat_interval=>'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=11',
   comments=>'Proc diario 11am'
);
END;
/
```

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_JOB'
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Any ideas what are we doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the `ownname`, I presume. Where did you find it (in documentation)?

---

Here's a working example; see if it helps.

First, connected as `SYS`, I'm granting required privileges to user `SCOTT` who will be creating a job.

```
SQL> grant execute on dbms_scheduler to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant create job to scott;

Grant succeeded.
```

Connect as SCOTT:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@pdb1
Connected.
```

Dummy procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /

Procedure created.
```

Create job (this is your code, fixed):

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
  3  (  job_name        => 'PROC_TKN_WA_FIX_ARREARS',
  4     job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
  5     job_action      => 'P_TEST;',
  6     start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
  7     repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=11',
  8     comments        => 'Proc diario 11am'
  9  );
 10  END;
 11  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I'll drop the job as I don't need it:

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_SCHEDULER.DROP_JOB('PROC_TKN_WA_FIX_ARREARS');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: thank you!!! this helped me!

Comment: You're welcome.